# Why freemarker.cache.TemplateCache has storeNegativeLookup?

Tags: freemarker

I have *template_update_delay=24h* for caching the templates for 24 hours. If my URLTemplateLoader gets IOException due to temporary outage(http status 429) then freemarker.cache.TemplateCache will call storeNegativeLookup and cached the exception too.

*cachedTemplate.templateOrException = e*

```
// Template source was removed
if (!newLookupResult.isPositive()) {
    if(debug) {
        LOG.debug(debugName + " no source found.");
    } 
    storeNegativeLookup(tk, cachedTemplate, null);
    return null;
}
private void storeNegativeLookup(TemplateKey tk, 
        CachedTemplate cachedTemplate, Exception e) {
    cachedTemplate.templateOrException = e;
    cachedTemplate.source = null;
    cachedTemplate.lastModified = 0L;
    storeCached(tk, cachedTemplate);
}
```

Later even if the URL endpoint is up and available, freemarker.cache.TemplateCache:getTemplate() will keep picking the cachedTemplate with the IOException and will keep rethrowing the exception till the cache is not expired.

```
else if(t instanceof IOException) {
   rethrown = true;
   throwLoadFailedException((IOException)t);
}
```

This is causing application of fail all the time ((.

How can I force Freemarker to retry fetching the template from the source instead of cache if there was an exception happened last time?

Answer (score 0):

Failed lookups are cached for the same reason successful ones are. A failed lookup can take as much or even more time (if for example a connection timeout is involved) as a successful one, and so can jam the application if it's for a frequently used template (by consuming the whole thread pool for example).

The problem is that there's only a single `templateUpdateDelay`. But it's possible that you want to use a different one depending what the cause of the error was. You should open a feature request for that on Jira.

What can you do right now though. You can catch the exception thrown by `Configuration.getTemplate`, and walk the cause trace to find out if the root cause is an exception that you don't want to cache, and then call `Configuration.removeTemplateFromCache` (but consider if you should only do it once in a certain time interval). I'm not sure if the exception with HTTP 429 can be recognized reliably out-of-the-box, or you have to customize the `TemplateLoader` so that the thrown exception contains the necessary information.